# Trying to keep updating one jframe

Tags: java

So I created a program that when you run it you can enter in score for a football game. Whenever the score updates I want the program to show a JFrame with the score on it. When I start the program it shows the score but whenever the score updates it creates a completely new window with the updated score. Is it possible to have the score stay on one JFrame?

```
 package com.football.main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.RootPaneContainer;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Main {




    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{




        String b;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.println("           ");  
    System.out.println("           ");  
    System.out.println("           ");  
    System.out.println("           ");  
    System.out.println("           ");  


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "College? If yes type College. If Pro type Pro.", "Pick a type", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        b = in.nextLine();
        if(b.equals("College")){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("           ");  
        System.out.println("           ");  
        System.out.println("           ");  
        System.out.println("           ");  
        System.out.println("           ");  

            College();  
        }
    private static  void College() throws InterruptedException {
        String t;
        String r;
        int s = 0;
        int s1 = 0;
        int to = 7;
        int f = 3;
        String w;
        String h;
        String u;
        String i;
        int y = 1;
        boolean isRunning = true;
        int sa = 2;

     String g;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You chose College!", "You chose college", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        Thread.sleep(300);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Please enter the first teams name!", "You chose college", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            t = in.nextLine();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Please enter the second teams name!", "You chose college", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            r = in.nextLine();
            while(isRunning = true){
                w = (t + ": " + s );

                h = (r + ": " + s1);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Score");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(w);
                textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
                frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                u = in.nextLine();
                if(u.equals(t)){
                    System.out.println("If " + t + " got a touchdown type T. If they got a field goal type F. If they got a safety type S. If you need to add one point just because type +1. If you need to subtract one point just because type -1.");
                    i = in.nextLine();
                    if(i.equals("T")){

                    s = s + to;
                    frame.remove(frame);
                    }

                    if(i.equals("F")){
                    s = s + f;
                    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                    }
                    if(i.equals("S")){
                    s = s + sa;
                    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                    }
                    if(i.equals("+1")){
                    s = s + y;
                    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                    }
                   if(i.equals("-1")){
                     s = s - y;  
                     frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                   }
                }
                else if(u.equals(r)) {
                    System.out.println("If " + r + " got a touchdown type T. If they got a field goal type F. If they got a safety type S. If you need to add one point just because type +1. If you need to subtract one point just because type -1.");
                    i = in.nextLine();
                    if(i.equals("T")){

                        s1 = s1 + to;
                        }

                    if(i.equals("F")){
                    s1 = s1 + f;
                    }
                    if(i.equals("S")){
                    s1 = s + sa;
                    }
                    if(i.equals("+1")){
                        s1 = s1 + y;
                    }
                    if(i.equals("-1")){
                        s1 = s1 - y;
                    }
                }
                else if(u.equals("Done")){
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("That is not a valid team.");
                }
            } 

        }
```

Comment: Well, in your code you are explicitly creating a new frame each time: `JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Score");`. Why don't you create the frame only once outside of the loop ?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use a switch-case statement instead of numerous if-statements

Answer (score 0):

Create a `new JFrame()` once, remember it as a variable, and keep updating the score on that JFrame.

Ex:

```
public JFrame frame = new JFrame("Score");
```

Then place a `JLabel` or whatever you want on that frame, and update it whenever the score updates